# My Windows colors are totally washed out ... but not always

Tags: windows, colors

I observed my browsers not displaying the colors I am used to on certain websites I frequent. While editing a screenshot in Windows Photos I saw something *wild*, I made a photo of this. As you can see the active area has the colors completely washed out while the shadowed region has vivid, outstanding colors -- these are the colors I am expecting. What has happened here??

[image]

Comment: I see no difference between those colors organ than an expected slight change due to using the snippet tool.

Comment: We cannot judge anything from a single photo. Please provide a screenshot of the same, and, if possible, a link, too. Also try not to take the photo at an angle. With a TN flat panel display, this can already severely distort colors.

Comment: Wrong display profile, probably. Possibility of having changed alpha/contrast in Accessibility, or even by pushing buttons on the display itself, which tends to wash out light colours too. This one of those instances a photo [as Daniel says, a *better* photo] may be more useful than a screenshot; though both would let us compare what the computer thinks it's showing to what you think it's showing.

Answer (score 0):

> Possibility of having changed alpha/contrast in Accessibility, or even by pushing buttons on the display itself, which tends to wash out light colours too

Aye. It's contrast. If I set the display contrast to 42, it's bad, at 43 suddenly it becomes great. I have no idea why. The change is *very* abrupt. https://photos.app.goo.gl/TnbTtLvHRoj8BrR6A

Comment: There ya go. Glad you got it. It's a nice reminder as to how far from accurate most consumer setups are - & their owners will never be aware until something squeezes it too far out of tolerance. I'd love to see the original site to see what the colours are *supposed* to be, as I have a fully calibrated system here, but I can see it doesn't look like something for the public eye, so no worries. Your computer, btw, has not the vaguest clue you're pushing buttons on the screen, it's information simply not available to it - so cannot do anything to try compensate or correct.

Comment: It's https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal No matter what transpired, I _am_ chx still, so of course it is.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks. I did a composite at sRGB [internet standard defaults]. It's unlikely you'll see my half exactly as it appears to me, but actually each of those colours is a strong 255 in its primary, with a reasonably balanced 'other two colours' each time. It looks good, strong but not overbearing. You'll see, even without absolute reference, that  yours is well 'under-powered' in all tones, grey by comparison. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHg78.jpg If you don't do colour work I doubt you'll ever have need to care, but just so you know. All the best. :)

Comment: Some of that grey could be caused by the camera, of course - another random variable.